# Theoretical form of the rank of the low rank approximation matrix

Tags: covariance-matrix, svd, matrix-decomposition

The low-rank matrix approximation problem involves finding
of a rank k version of a m × n matrix A, labeled $A_k$,
such that $A_k$ is as ”close” as possible to the best SVD approximation
version of A at the same rank level. Let's suppose $y^{*} = N_{n}(\mu_x ,  C_{xx})$ is the marginal distribution of the response vector Y under the orginal model and let $y^{**} = N_{n}(\mu_x ,  C_{xx}^{lp})$ denote the linear projection approximation.

If $||C_{xx} - C_{xx}^{lp}||_{F} \leq \epsilon$, the error in the approximation of the co-variance matrix, then the $$ KL(y^{*}, y^{**}) \leq  {(n + n/d)^2}\epsilon $$

Find the theoretical form of the rank in $C_{xx}^{lp}$